# If do not click , the mainWindow is nil, right after launching and right mouse clicked and popup menuItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Our app is similar with this,[just like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkrNp.png)

after launching, without any other operation, if I right mouse click, 
[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow = (null);

but if I did click somewhere or do any operation, the mainWindow is right;
I need the mainWindow to call ***makeFirstResponder*** method, so how to make it not null?

Answer (score 1):

I have obtained a solution. Since I just need a window not MainWindow, so try this

```
NSWindow *mainWindow = self.view.window;
if (self.view.window == nil) {
    mainWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication].windows lastObject];
}
```

then the mainWindow can't be nil any more.

Comment: I have found that if `self.view.window` (or I use `[NSApp mainWindow]`) is NOT null, then the window returned using `lastObject` is the same as the non-null value.  So, I confirming that this solution works.  But, why not just skip that first line and skip the test and simply always fetch the window from `lastObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Swift solution

```
NSApp.windows.first
```

If you're using this at launch be sure that there are no other windows as the only limitation of this is that it displays all windows in an unpredictable order